# Severe Muscle cramp during abdomen crunch

Tags: muscle, pain, abdominals, crunches, cramps

I have fat around my Belly, and whenever I try to do Abdomen crunch, I get severe (or massive) muscle cramp in my belly which prevents me from doing anything for next 30 minutes due to intense pain.

I know I need to overcome this in order to continue doing it - Is there anything like a warm up can help?

Thanks,

Comment: How much fat around your belly? What is your waist circumference?  More or less than than 40 inches (101.6 cm)?

Comment: Its 40 inches, and yes, I have fat around belly. :-(

Answer (score 3):

It depends on many thing and **I would recommend consulting a doctor before continuing on.**

Having said that crunches are meant to do this 
`Remember what superman said no pain no gain` :)

Make sure not to drink too much water or eat too much food before exercise. I am not asking to dehydrate yourself at all but stay away from excess water during exercise and just have enough food as to not collapse due to lack of energy but you do not need a full stomach either.

Other than that you should be happy and enjoy this because this is the fruit of your hardwork.